# How to use web, API and thirds applications (google+, facebook, ...) authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, devise, google-plus

I'm working on a rails application and I need to authenticate users using email, facebook and google +. The rails app is a web and an API application which means I need token and session authentication. I thought about those options :

1. Using devise gem for user structure and devise_token_auth gem for the API authentication. PROBLEM : As devise_token_auth creates the user's table in the database again, I can't make work the 2 gems together.
2. I found [this article](http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/01/19/the-one-with-a-json-api-login-using-devise/) that shows how to make API authentication using devise which is great for email authentication only BUT it will be difficult to use for facebook and google + authentication,

How do you use to implement authentication in your Web and API rails application ?

Thank you!